# cannot get a vb6 control with a color function to work in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, colors, vb6, ocx

I have a vb6 ocx control that has a function that takes, among other things, a long to set the color of a label component of the control. This all works fine until you use the control in a vb.net 64bit environment where longs are ints and color is a different type anyway.

I tried changing the function to take 3 ints for rgb and then using the rgb function to get the color to use but the form will not load in the vb.net environment with the control on it.

Does anyone know how I can change the control's code in vb6 so that it can be used in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a built in method to get the equivalent color value to use in your application:

```
Dim myColor As Color = Color.Red

' Translate myColor to an OLE color. 
Dim winColor As Integer = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(myColor)
```

The result is an `Int32` which is a `Long` in VB6

So...

In your VB6 control you can expose a Color property like this:

```
Public Property Get ColorValue as Long
    ColorValue = lblColor.BackColor
End Property

Public Property Let ColorValue(value as Long)
    lblColor.BackColor = value
End Property
```

Then in you VB.NET application you can set it like this:

```
MyControl.ColorValue = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red)
```

Comment: how can I use the colortranslator class in a vb6 control? isn't that a .net class?

Comment: Your question was not that clear are you trying to code in VB6 or VB.NET because you've tagged both in your question

Comment: my apologies. I have a vb6 ocx control that I am trying to use in vb.net

Comment: that looks like it might work. I had made a cludge solution by sticking a few invisible labels on the control with different color backgrounds and was able to set the color by passing a string saying which label to use so this looks promising. I will not be able to test it now for a little while. Thank you for the solution.